# Parsing big XML file - having unescaped html tags - throws error

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

Am trying to import data from a **large 1 GB XML file** into WordPress. As it's a big file, I did some research and found that this would be the best solution: https://github.com/prewk/xml-string-streamer

I implemented a test script like this:

```
<?php
require('vendor/autoload.php');

// Convenience method for creating a file streamer with the default parser
$streamer = Prewk\XmlStringStreamer::createStringWalkerParser("mybigfile.xml");


$count = 1;
while ($node = $streamer->getNode()) {    
    echo $node . '<br>';
    
    $simpleXmlNode = simplexml_load_string($node);    

    if( $simpleXmlNode AND $simpleXmlNode->getName() == 'book' )
    {
        var_dump( $simpleXmlNode );

        echo  (string)$simpleXmlNode->name. '<br>';        
        
        echo $count++. '<br>';    
    }    
    
    if( $count == 20 ) die;
}
```

Upto 10 nodes, everything seems to work fine. But after that, there's a `<description>` element and inside it, there's some unescaped HTML tags (eg: `<div>`). So it's throwing errors because of these HTML tags.

My XML file looks somewhat like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<source>
    <lastBuildDate>2021-04-24</lastBuildDate>
    <owner>Blahblah</owner>

    <book>
        <name><![CDATA[Once upon a time in coma]]></name>
        <price><![CDATA[USD 20]]></price>                      
        <listDate><![CDATA[2021-04-02]]></listDate>
        <description><![CDATA[<div>This is a great book..</div>]]></description>
    </book>

    <book>
        <name><![CDATA[Once upon a time in coma]]></name>
        <price><![CDATA[USD 20]]></price>                      
        <listDate><![CDATA[2021-04-02]]></listDate>
        <description><![CDATA[<div>This is a great book..</div>]]></description>
    </book>


    <book>
        <name><![CDATA[Once upon a time in coma]]></name>
        <price><![CDATA[USD 20]]></price>                      
        <listDate><![CDATA[2021-04-02]]></listDate>
        <description><![CDATA[<div>This is a great book..</div>]]></description>
    </book>

</source>
```

Content is not always same, I just gave you an example. I believe the XML reader is having hard time understanding which are the XML elements because of the HTML elements inside `<description>` tag. How can I convert the HTML tags to HTML entities on the fly?

Comment: I think you have misdiagnosed the problem. No XML parser is going to have trouble understanding well-formed CDATA sections. If you told us what the error messages are, we might have some chance of helping you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this solution and it is not clear what is your exact error message. However did you try to set `expectGT` option as `true` from here https://github.com/prewk/xml-string-streamer#available-options-for-the-stringwalker-parser ?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I spoke too soon. I just took a look at the source code of the library you are using. It looks to me like something that someone knocked up in a weekend. It might well be incapable of parsing this input.

Comment: @MichaelKay thank you. It was throwing parse errors like this: `simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 44: parser error : CData section not finished &lt;div&gt;&lt;p&gt;`

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky thank you! That resolved my problem! Can you please post it as an answer so that I could mark it as accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `expectGT` option as `true`. Have a look at https://github.com/prewk/xml-string-streamer#available-options-for-the-stringwalker-parser

Comment: I'm glad it helped you.

Comment: That's just weird, that you have to set a specific option to make it accept well-formed XML.